# I want to find first and last values of two columns along with my query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT Min(`low`), 
       Max(`high`), 
       `snapshotdatetime` 
FROM   `historical_intraday_price` 
WHERE  Unix_timestamp(`snapshotdatetime`) >= Unix_timestamp('2016-09-01 09:20:00.000000 ') 
GROUP  BY Unix_timestamp(`snapshotdatetime`) DIV 180
```

This is my query  i want first value of field name Open and last value of field name Close with this query.
its smthng like

```
SELECT First(`open`), 
       Last(`close`), 
       Min(`low`), 
       Max(`high`), 
       `snapshotdatetime` 
FROM   `historical_intraday_price` 
WHERE  Unix_timestamp(`snapshotdatetime`) >= Unix_timestamp('2016-09-01 09:20:00.000000     ') 
GROUP  BY Unix_timestamp(`snapshotdatetime`) DIV 180
```

but  FIRST(`Open`),LAST(`Close`) are wil not work,anybody have any idea,please help

Comment: which type are the columns Opne and Close ? are date ? .. update your question adding  data sample and expeceted result

Comment: no,its double values ,that are prices like 256.25,245.74 etc

Comment: Then first and last what mean .. first and last in ordered list ? .. min and max value?

Comment: that are price fields with a data type of double

Comment: what mean first and last  ?.. look at my previous comment

Comment: my query is to fetch data in every 3 minute interval,first of Open means First value of that interval and Last means last value of that interval

Comment: Stop trying to add details in comments, and [edit] your question instead to make it more clear what you're asking. Burying details in comments mean that people can't see them. We shouldn't have to ask you 20 questions to pry the details from you. Put them in your post.

Comment: This is a [_"groupwise max"_](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/groupwise-max-in-mariadb/) problem.  (Actually max and min.)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe use a UNION? Something like this?

```
SELECT MAX(open), MAX(close), MIN(low), MAX(high), MAX(snapshotDateTime)
FROM (
    SELECT `open`, NULL AS close, MIN(`low`) AS low, MAX(`high`) AS high, `snapshotDateTime`
    FROM table
    WHERE [condition(s)]
    GROUP BY `snapshotDateTime`
    ORDER BY `snapshotDateTime`
    LIMIT 1
    UNION ALL 
        SELECT NULL, `close`, MIN(`low`), MAX(`high`), `snapshotDateTime`
        FROM table
        WHERE [condition(s)]
        GROUP BY `snapshotDateTime`
        ORDER BY `snapshotDateTime` DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) U
```